# Unable to load momd file in ios 9 iPhone 4 simulator

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9, nsmanagedobject

I am using Core data with **iOS 9.0, iPhone4 Simulator & Xcode 9.2**.

While loading `momd` file application crashes with nil value.

Although i already added `Address.xcdatamodel` file to bundle resource & **target membership** checkbox selected.

```
lazy var managedObjectModelForAddress: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.    
        let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Address", withExtension: "momd")!//Crashes here.
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
    }()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using many `.xcdatamodel` files some of them get worked with Solution1 & some with solution 2

**Solution 1:**

- Delete App from simulator
- Delete `.xcdatamodel` from xcode & save it somewhere, & re add it.
- Quit Xcode, Delete Derived data & Repoen XCODE.

**Solution 2:**

- Delete App from simulator
- Create new `.xcdatamodel` & copy all contains to new `.xcdatamodel` file
- Quit Xcode, Delete Derived data & Repoen XCODE.